# Keep getting messages, Socket

Tags: android, sockets, service, android-intentservice

I have a scenario which I need to resolve. Currently I'm able to connect to an embedded system through socket connection, via android device.

I was able to use asynctask to send xml commands and receive them back, update UI with the results. But on the last step I need to use a command which will start the system to work, and I will keep getting messages from the system. it will be sent variously and the time can be different (we are talking about few 200-500 ms).

**So my question is:**

- Asynctask wouldn't work. Because the 'work' varies more than 100ms and I'm not sure when the messages will be send, So I can't use async and show dialog for unknown time.
- I have read that intent-service or service can do this work, but I'm not sure yet if it will be a good solution.

What would be a good solution for receiving these messages and for updating the UI?

Comment: You do not have to use a dialog with an asynctask.

Comment: yea than the ui will be not accessible?

Comment: Why? Of course you can handle gui things. It is an AsyncTask you know. You can update the gui in the usual way with publish progress and onProgressUpdate().

Comment: @greenapps yea but the system can send message anytime. I cant let a asynctask running until a message appers?

Comment: Let it run. What's the problem? And didn't you try meanwhile?